# SQL LEFT JOIN with a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and trying to build a query in a way that I can't seem to get working.

I have two tables.  One table has a list of ItemTypes and another with a list of mappings between ItemTypes and users.

I want to have a query that will return these results:

```
ID   | ItemType      | Enabled?
---------------------------------
1    | Type1         | false
2    | Type2         | true
```

The Enabled column is going to be based on whether there is an entry in the other table.  I want to use some sort of case statement where if the LEFT JOIN item exists, then put TRUE otherwise put FALSE.

```
SELECT systype.ID, systype.TypeDescription, 
'Enable' = CASE hid.ID WHEN NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM [HardwareTestcaseManagement].[dbo].[A7_SystemItemTypes] systype
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[A7_HiddenNewsFeedTypes] hid 
ON systype.ID = hid.SystemItemTypesID
AND hid.UserName = @UserName
```

However, this query I've come up with so far ^ is not working quite as I intended.

Any suggestions how I can tweak this query to work how I want it to?

EDIT: When I do a left join and just select the column "hid.ID" it comes back as either NULL or the actual ID.  I was hoping I could modify the value based on whether it was null or not.

Comment: @Nenad actually that's an outer table, so there could very well be cases where it is NULL. (That's technically not a WHERE clause, it's JOIN criteria.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand .. My bad, I don't know how but I thought I've seen `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: Also please use `[square brackets]` instead of `'single quotes'` for column aliases. The latter is deprecated in multiple forms *and* makes your alias look like a string. Or better yet, don't use a keyword or don't bother escaping it anyway - it isn't necessary. `SELECT Enable = 1;` works just fine, except that `Enable` appears in blue in SSMS, due to IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare `null` values like other values. Use the `is null` operator in the `case`:

```
'Enable' = CASE WHEN hid.ID IS NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I had just phrased the CASE statement improperly.  Worked great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and efficient approach is to use `EXISTS` instead of a join:

```
SELECT systype.ID, systype.TypeDescription, 
       [Enable] = CASE WHEN EXISTS( 
                     SELECT 1 FROM A7_HiddenNewsFeedTypes ft
                     WHERE ft.SystemItemTypesID = systype.ID
                     AND ft.UserName = @UserName
                  ) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END
FROM [HardwareTestcaseManagement].[dbo].[A7_SystemItemTypes] systype
```

Comment: still needs some WHERE on outer query, or no?

Comment: @vasja why? There's no filter in the original query against the A7_SystemItemTypes table.

Comment: Ok, I now I see (my wrong guess of what's in the table since no sample provided)

Answer (score 2):

There are two formats of [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). You need to use `Searched Case` *NOT* `Simple Case` when checking `null` values;

```
SELECT systype.ID, systype.TypeDescription, 
      CASE WHEN hid.UserName IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END Enabled
FROM [HardwareTestcaseManagement].[dbo].[A7_SystemItemTypes] systype
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[A7_HiddenNewsFeedTypes] hid 
         ON systype.ID = hid.SystemItemTypesID
         AND hid.UserName = @UserName
```

Comment: I guess, this will never return false because of WHERE hid.UserName = @UserName

Comment: Why did you change the hid.UserName join criteria to a filter? You've just changed this from a left join to an inner join.

Comment: Ah, sorry that was a mistake, I was concentrating on CASE, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT systype.ID, systype.TypeDescription, 
CASE WHEN hid.SystemItemTypesID IS NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as Enable
FROM [HardwareTestcaseManagement].[dbo].[A7_SystemItemTypes] systype
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[A7_HiddenNewsFeedTypes] hid 
ON systype.ID = hid.SystemItemTypesID
AND hid.UserName = @UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT systype.ID, systype.TypeDescription, 
'Enable' = CASE
     WHEN hid.UserName = @UserName THEN 'true'
     ELSE 'false'
   END
FROM [HardwareTestcaseManagement].[dbo].[A7_SystemItemTypes] systype
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[A7_HiddenNewsFeedTypes] hid 
ON systype.ID = hid.SystemItemTypesID
-- no join on UserName
```

Comment: If there's many users, will scan many rows since join on UserName was removed (that's why distinct was added)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it without using `CASE`

```
'Enable' = isnull(nullif(isnull(hid.id,'false'),hid.id),'true')
```